# Sum up two MAT files

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to add/sum/merge two MAT files. Both the files contain only numeric values. Basically like this:
'file_1' contains

```
2 0 2 0 1 0...
3 0 9 0 2 0...
1 0 6 0 7 0...
...
```

'file_2.mat' contains

```
0 1 0 9 0 7 ...
0 5 0 5 0 8 ...
0 9 0 1 0 2 ...
...
```

i.e. in both files every alternate columns are zero. I want to merge them and form like this:

```
2 1 2 9 1 7...
3 5 9 5 2 8...
1 9 6 1 7 2...
...
```

and save this as a new mat file, 'file_3.mat'. And write this new file as an Image. How to do it?

Comment: A `.mat` file can't contain "only numeric values". `.mat` files contain _variables_

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `A` contains the first matrix and `B` contains the second, you just need to do:

```
C = A + B
```

Example:

```
% create dummy values
A = magic(5);
A(:,1:2:5) = 0;

B = magic(5);
B(:,2:2:5) = 0;

C = A + B
```

This will output:

```
C =

17    24     1     8    15
23     5     7    14    16
 4     6    13    20    22
10    12    19    21     3
11    18    25     2     9
```

Comment: But I am not adding matrices. I am trying to add contents of MAT files.

Comment: @Swaroop what do the MAT files really contain? each a single matrix?

Comment: @Swaroop - if each file contains one matrix then the solution above will work.

Comment: Hi, I am extremely sorry. I asked wrong question. MAT files contain workspace variables. I confused it to contents of variables. I am sorry to waste your time. Thank you @m.s. for making me think what a MAT file contains. And also the method you suggested worked. Thanks again.